# How to wrap long lines inside of markdown ``` code ``` in Github and Gitlab issues?

Tags: github, markdown, gitlab, word-wrap

eg:

````
```
some very long line; some very long line; some very long line; some very long line; some very long line; some very long line; some very long line; some very long line; some very long line; some very long line; 
```
````

will force user to scroll in github/gitlab issues.
Is there a way to soft-line wrap inside `code block` ?

I've read the related questions but they seem different (eg jekyll etc).

EDIT: manually editing code to limit to 80 columns is not a viable option (eg, when pasting from a compiler output/log etc; that's a lot of work and should not be necessary)

EDIT: see also https://github.com/softvar/enhanced-github/issues/95

Comment: I don't think you can. The easiest thing to control in this case is to make sure each line is a reasonable length. For example, some people recommend up to 80 characters per line maximum.

Comment: If you are copy and pasting, then copy into a proper text editor, use the editors built-in line wrapping features to hard-wrap the lines, then copy out and into your destination. This is the only consistently automated solution I've ever seen.

Comment: In stackoverflow markdown, you simply can't, it seems. You can't even with HTML tags, because the style attribute is stripped out.

Comment: Interesting. Until a solution comes along, perhaps using a [permanent link to a code snippet](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet) could be an alternate approach.

Answer (score 84):

A quick workaround is to quote your codeblocks, e.g.

> `this line is very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long`

Make sure you keep the three backticks inline with the very long line. Like this:

````
> ```this line is very long```
````

Comment: This is effectively the same as just wrapping the line with single `

Comment: A quoted block of text has a different meaning than a non-quoted block of text. Quoting a code block just to get it to wrap the text changes the meaning. This answer is the equivalent to saying, "just wrap your code in an `<h1>` tag." Sure, maybe it works, but it's ugly.

Answer (score 36):

Add below CSS in your output HTML file
or
edit it in the linked CSS

```css
code {
  white-space : pre-wrap !important;
}
```

Comment: The question is about GitHub, not some HTML page you might have.

Comment: That did solve my problem (partially). It is wrapping lines on my page now but it doesn't respect the indentation. Is there any way I can wrap the lines and respect the code indentation?

Comment: MD support `HTML `tags by design.. so use `style` tag if you need

Comment: @OrCohen you know markdown lets you use some html tags, right? And from the look of it now, github supports all the tags I've ever really used. I, too, tend to avoid them but they complement nicely when there's no other options. I myself abuse `<details>`/`<summary>` tags.

Comment: Worked in mkdocs-material so well! Gracias! 

Comment: This is THE answer I have been looking for, for ages. In my case I was looking for a solution for HTML docs exported from VSCode. This solved my problem, so I ain't mad that it's on a GitHub/GitLab question.

Answer (score 22):

Instead of wrapping your code with triple backticks ```` ``` ```` wrap it with `<code>...</code>` tags.

This new feature was added to GitLab in Feb 2022.

Comment: “was added to GitLab ” but this is a link to GitHub.

Comment: The link is indeed wrong. Unfortunately I wasn't be able to find the right URL, so I'm gonna remove it.

Comment: I guess this sort of works but the formatting is very ugly...

Comment: Not perfect, but it does the job on GitHub. +1.

Answer (score 21):

The imperfect workaround I currently use is to replace the

````
```
````

with a single backtick:

```
`
```

...and do that line by line. which is infeasible for larger code chunks, and also makes highlighting the code harder for viewers of the markdown. So this 'line by line' workaround is strongly inferior to a genuine code wrap for code contained inside ```.

Comment: have to point out, ` quoted string may render markdown format, 
but in ``` was show as plain

Answer (score 13):

## Simple: Use extension like [User Css](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-css/okpjlejfhacmgjkmknjhadmkdbcldfcb)

Code for default `pre code` (this too) and gitlab

```css
pre code,  /* stackoverflow */
.md:not(.use-csslab) pre code
 {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

[image: pre code pre-wrap]

Or use another extension, like [JSScript triks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odialddippdmebbfbflcneemfdglimod) for full control of own js/css

## Switch "Wrap/Unwrap" for pre code anywhere:

**in JS section add switch init:**

jQuery example to add an switch (checkbox) only for long lines

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/57341170/5447232
var ws = function(i,e) { 
  $("pre code").filter(function(){
   var _t = $(this).parent();
    return !_t.has("input[switch").length 
      && _t.get(0).scrollWidth > _t.innerWidth();
  }).before("<input type='checkbox' checked switch title='Wrap/Unwrap' />");
}
$("body").on("change", ws).change();
$(window).bind("scroll", ws);
```

**in CSS section add styles:**

Styles, depend checkbox status

```css
/* https://stackoverflow.com/a/57341170/5447232 */
pre {position:relative;}
input[type="checkbox"][switch] {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right:0.5em;
  top:0.5em;
}
pre input[switch]:checked + code { white-space: pre-wrap; }
/* pre input[switch]:not(:checked) + code { white-space: pre; } */
```

[image]
[image]

See code at https://gitlab.com/MrSwed/wrap-unwrap-for-pre-code

Answer (score 7):

Looks like this is not possible yet. But you can use some extensions to work around the markup on GitHub -  this [chrome extension](https://github.com/yoheimuta/github-pre-utility) here is pretty cool,
See this [github thread here](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/168) for more

Comment: thanks for the link ! only addresses github, not gitlab; reported issue in  https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/25850

Answer (score 7):

For non-github places where markdown is supported, extending @Tarun's answer (which works great for regular HTML pages) as follows:

If you don't have access to external CSS, just add the following `<style>` on the same page:

```
<style>
  code {
    white-space : pre-wrap !important;
    word-break: break-word;
  }
</style>
```

All code blocks on that page will be word-wrapped. The `word-break: break-word` will avoid breaking the words across lines.

(SO's question is about Github issues specifically, but putting this down as an answer here since this is the first link on Google that appears for wrapping lines in code blocks in markdown - and would be helpful to many people as evident from the upvotes on similar answer)

Comment: I tried this in https://github.com/timotheecour/Nim/issues/734#issue-892377990 but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @timotheecour `github` probably strips out the style tags and hence it doesn't work there even though it supports markdown. The above answer was an extension to @TarunKhurana's answer which is applicable to regular HTML pages or other places where markdown is accepted. 

I have updated the answer accordingly, now

Comment: This works for fenced code blocks in CodiMD/HackMD.

Answer (score -10):

Found following solution for myself and tested it on the "github":

1) Create file with suffix ".md"

2) Use **<*div*>** tag to solve the requested goal - splitting up long lines into several making it be marked down as one line.

Example:

```
<div>I am
very
long line</div>
```

Will be viewed as following:

```
I am very long line
```

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what the OP is trying to do.