# There's anyway to enable Word Wrap in Github code pages?

Tags: github

There's a way to enable word wrap in github's code pages?

I hate having to scroll left to right when reading code.

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis No, my question refers to code pages, not "code blocks" as I had previously mentioned in the title.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question, I replace my previous comment (since after time passes comments cannot be edited) with this comment, mentioning as possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41238148/1959808

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I Soft-wrap code in GitHub's file viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75186349/how-can-i-soft-wrap-code-in-githubs-file-viewer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no option in Github AFAIK, but I use a [theme](https://userstyles.org/styles/124860/github-code-wrap) for [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) to achieve this

Comment: Wow. I've searched for month for a tampermonkey script. And it's a style (That I have with a dark theme installed too).  
Btw I've changed from _break-all_ to _normal_ in _word-warp_. I think that works better for me.

Comment: **Beware of deceptive advertisements** if attempting to install this theme!  For example, I received [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiCeW.jpg) in which the large "Download" button and instructions are fake and the actual install button is the smaller "Install Style" button.

Comment: i think this is out of date now because ti was wrking romemuntil today.